# Why does my subquery logic give me a different result?

Tags: database, postgresql, analysis

I got a different answer(4434.21) than the supposed result(4721.14)([ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zHNi.jpg) and can't figure out what went wrong, question below:

Q: What is the lifetime average amount spent in terms of total_amt_usd, including only the companies that spent more per order, on average, than the average of all orders.

```
WITH t1 AS (SELECT AVG(o.total_amt_usd) total_avg
FROM orders o),

t2 AS(SELECT a.name account_name,
       a.id account_id,
       AVG(o.total_amt_usd) account_avg
FROM accounts a
JOIN orders o
  ON a.id = o.account_id
GROUP BY 1,2
HAVING AVG(o.total_amt_usd) > (SELECT * 
                              FROM t1)
)

SELECT AVG(o.total_amt_usd) 
FROM orders o
JOIN t2 
  ON t2.account_id = o.account_id
```

Solution：

```
SELECT AVG(avg_amt)
FROM (
    SELECT o.account_id,
           AVG(o.total_amt_usd) avg_amt
    FROM orders o 
        GROUP BY 1
        HAVING AVG(o.total_amt_usd) > 
        (SELECT AVG(o.total_amt_usd) avg_all
        FROM orders o)
) t1
```

Comment: Please spend a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. Then update you question to contain (at minimum) table definition (ddl)  and sample data, all as formatted text (see [Senseful Solutions](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/) or even better a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). With that your question can be reopened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En..both query are different. First query gets the average of o.total_amt_usd of orders satisfying the join condition. Second query gets the average of average of o.total_amt_usd of orders satisfying some conditions. you might get same result  if you use SELECT AVG(t2.account_avg)
FROM orders o
JOIN t2
ON t2.account_id = o.account_id.

Comment: Yeah I understand what's the issue now, I think I read the question wrong, changing the last part to SELECT AVG(account_avg)
FROM t2

Comment: I think I read the question wrong in the beginning. I interpreted it as calculates the average total_amt_usd by order, not by company/account. And joining the t2 in my code suggested so, as it considered only the orders associated with the accounts that met the condition in t2. By changing the last part of my code to below render the same result as the solution code:

SELECT AVG(account_avg)
FROM t2